# Using WebView.Load() to read dynamic HTML with references to JS libraries?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to write a class that will return a string of HTML with Javascript for use in a WebView.  Returning HTML and Javascript works well, but I'm having issues loading libraries with the returned HTML.  As an example, this works well:

```
public static String helloWorld() {
    String html;
    html =  "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title>" +
            "</title>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<script>" +
            "document.write(\"Hello, World\");" +
            "</script>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
    return html;
}
```

However, this does not:

```
public static String helloWorld() {
    String html;
    html =  "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title>" +
            "</title>" +
            "<script src=\"../assets/src/external_script.js\"></script>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<script>" +
            "external_script_function();" +
            "</script>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
    return html;
}
```

I'm guessing that the filepath for the external_script.js import is incorrect?  Using `WebView.LoadUrl(myLocalHtmlFile);` works when using the other JS file. How would I go about making this work properly?  Or alternatively, is there a better way to achieve similar results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to feed the assets folder to the WebView as the base URL. Like this:

```
MyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", helloWorld());
```

And then the `<script>` tag would go like this:

```
<script src="src/external_script.js"></script>
```

Assuming the library resides under `assets/src`. And yes, you need to enable JavaScript like triad is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you write assets i suppose you are trying to load a file you put in Eclipse or what ever IDE you use that is bundled with your app. This gets stored inside your APK and AFAIK it does not get "unzipped" to the working-directory of your app.

This means that eighter you will have to manually place it on the SDcard or internal memory or load it internally and dynamically inject it into the final HTML before you send it to your WebView.

Personally i would go for the second method because it does make less of a mess.